# Change date and time with Deep Freeze installed

Tags: windows, deep-freeze

My computer has Windows 8 with Deep Freeze installed. I changed the date/time settings to be accurate, but the time soon changed back on its own (to an incorrect time). I then turned off the computer, changed the time settings, saved them, and started again. After a while, it got set back one hour.

How can I set my time so that it won't fluctuate?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform the following steps:

- Unfreeze the system
- Change the system time
- Freeze the system

If you are not an Administrator on the system or network, then you will have to get one involved so this can be changed.

---

If you are installing the software for the first time and want to always be able to adjust the system time, use the following command line options:

```
DFStd.exe /Install /PW=<password> /AllowTimeChange /Freeze=<comma separated drive letters>
```

This will allow any use to change the system time, even when the software is in the "frozen" state.

Answer (score 0):

when your computer starts up press F2, then  you c an see there the time and date. press F5 for decrease and press F6 for increase. then save it.

Comment: Is this specific to a particular model of computer?

Answer (score -1):

You can do what @Ramhound suggested or you can simply change the date and time settings from BIOS.

for more information you can visit this [site](http://pfortoday.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-change-computer-settings-with.html)

Comment: Please provide and quote relevant information from all reference links.